# Prevent shipping tax from doubling when item qty goes from 1 to 2 in cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

So.. it turns out commerce cannot apply tax to base shipping rates, see [Calculating (Product + Shipping) + Tax?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15785/craft-commerce-calculating-product-shipping-tax/15791) previously asked on stack.

I then tried setting the tax to a "Per Item Rate" to 99 and the "Maximum Total Shipping Cost" to 99, which I don't want exceeded no matter what. At first this seemed to work fine with a test product (price 5,-), however that was until I increased the qty to 2. The shipping cost for the cart stays at 99, however the shipping cost of the product doubles, which in this case also doubles the cart tax (20.8 to 41.6). This makes no sense to me.

I have attached a video demonstrating what I mean (I get the same result in the demo templates that come with commerce). See video: [watch directly on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8JsOGTrYBIjZUF6cFhTY2RVd0k)

We are just a week away from launch, and I just discovered this issue. Stressing out right now.

Thank you to anyone who can help enlighten me.

Comment: Can you send this to support@craftcommerce.com please.

Answer (score 3):

Since taxes apply currently only at the line item level, the tax is correctly applying to the item+shipping cost of the line item.

The shipping max cost is making a order level change to the baseShipping after all line items have been adjusted.

We are looking into supporting order level taxes only, to avoid this, and will update this answer soon with a solution.

Thanks.

UPDATE: This has been fixed, see answer here: [Craft Commerce: Calculating (Product + Shipping) + Tax?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15785/craft-commerce-calculating-product-shipping-tax?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Luke, I appreciate it. In the meantime I've had someone build a plugin for me that does the job :)